# How can flex-shrink win against padding?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex-box tag cloud that is being sized from the outside. I want tags inside it to be collapsible all the way down to zero if needed (an edge case). Right now, they will go only as far as 2x their padding.

[image]

Basically, I need a way to make `flex-shrink` "win" against `padding`.

If possible, I'd like to achieve that without using overflow: hidden, as that will interfere with other stuff that is inside this enclosure.

Runnable snippet:

```js
$('button').on('click', (e) => {
  $('.tags').css({
    width: $(e.target).text()
  });
});
```

```css
.tags {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: red;
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 20px 5px;
}
.tag {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.tag + .tag {
  margin-left: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Tags will not collapse beyond 2 x padding</h3>
<div class="tags" style="width: 200px">
  <div class="tag">Tag 1</div>
  <div class="tag">Tag 2</div>
  <div class="tag">Tag 3</div>
</div>
<br />
<div>
  <button>200px</button>
  <button>100px</button>
  <button>50px</button>
  <button>10px</button>
</div>
```

Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flex-shrink` can't win against padding, neither can a normal block element: [fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jd9sycwr/)

One way to make that work is to add an extra wrapper for the text and set padding/borders on it instead of the flex item.

```js
$('button').on('click', (e) => {
  $('.tags').css({
    width: $(e.target).text()
  });
});
```

```css
.tags {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: red;
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 20px 5px;
}
.tag {
  flex-shrink: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.tag div {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.tag + .tag {
  margin-left: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Tags will not collapse beyond 2 x padding</h3>
<div class="tags" style="width: 200px">
  <div class="tag"><div>Tag 1</div></div>
  <div class="tag"><div>Tag 2</div></div>
  <div class="tag"><div>Tag 3</div></div>
</div>
<br />
<div>
  <button>200px</button>
  <button>100px</button>
  <button>50px</button>
  <button>10px</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks!